# How to bind the json objects with the grouping of same elements in angular

Tags: json, angular, datatables

[How to bind these data in datatables at angular 6 for showing the attenance details this really very confusing to me kindly help me to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qFE4.png)

{"content":{"27-09-2018":[{"id":5,"empid":{"userid":7,"firstName":"Amanullah","lastName":"H","jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_MEMBER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"amanullah.h@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"14-02-2018","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"aman.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":7,"department":"JAVA"},"date":"27-09-2018","status":true},{"id":6,"empid":{"userid":6,"firstName":"Anns Jarigo","lastName":"PaulRaj","jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_MEMBER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"annsjarigo.p@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"24-02-2018","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"anns.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":6,"department":"JAVA"},"date":"27-09-2018","status":true}],"28-09-2018":[{"id":1,"empid":{"userid":7,"firstName":"Amanullah","lastName":"H","jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_MEMBER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"amanullah.h@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"14-02-2018","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"aman.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":7,"department":"JAVA"},"date":"28-09-2018","status":true},{"id":2,"empid":{"userid":6,"firstName":"Anns Jarigo","lastName":"PaulRaj","jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_MEMBER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"annsjarigo.p@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"24-02-2018","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"anns.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":6,"department":"JAVA"},"date":"28-09-2018","status":true},{"id":3,"empid":{"userid":8,"firstName":"Raj Prabhu","lastName":"A","jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_MEMBER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"rajprabu.a@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"26-07-2018","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"raj.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":8,"department":"JAVA"},"date":"28-09-2018","status":true},{"id":4,"empid":{"userid":5,"firstName":"Rudra","lastName":"Vanniyan","jobTitle":"DOTNET_DEVELOPER","position":"TEAM_LEADER","mode_of_employement":"Direct","phoneNumber":"9087881162","email":"rudra.r@binary2quantum.com","date_of_joining":"06-09-2017","reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com","image":"rudra.jpg","userRole":"EMPLOYEE","appUser":5,"department":"DOTNET"},"date":"28-09-2018","status":true}]},"status":"Success!"}

Comment: Post json data instead of image??

Comment: sure!! i updated my post with data kindly please give me a solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `object.keys` for this.

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dqdb1how-to-bind-the-json-objects-with-the-grouping-of?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
object=Object;
  data={  
   "content":{  
      "27-09-2018":[ 
        -----
      ]
   }
 }


<div *ngFor="let key of object.keys(data.content)">
  <p>{{key}}</p>
    <div *ngFor="let keyArray of data.content[key]">
    {{keyArray.empid.firstName}}
    </div>
</div>
```